# TeamCity forcing "checking for changes" only on agent

Tags: teamcity

I have the following set-up:

- TeamCity server running on one machine
- TeamCity agent on a separate machine, connected via VPN to source control (TFS).

The VPN is a bit tricky to set up to run as a service so can't/don't want to set it up on the server as well. Rather, I was hoping to have everything go through that agent.

The build server fails while collecting sources, it appears it's trying to figure out what changes were performed in TFS (but it can't find the TFS host since it's not on that VPN). The build is set to check out the sources only on the agent.

I'm afraid the answer is obvious, but couldn't find any documentation confirming this...Is it possible to have such a setup? Or does the build server need access to the TFS repo to check for changes and trigger builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TeamCity server will still require access to the VCS root to evaluate the current revision and changeset details.

It's important to note the additional side-effects of agent side checkout as well.  See [VCS Checkout Mode](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Mode) in the TeamCity docs for more information (note the 2nd line).

Comment: Interestingly I saw that page but skipped to the description of the agent checkout mode. Thanks for pointing out the (obvious) top part.